# Partial match in URL getSegment()

Tags: url, getsegment

Is there a way to partially match text in a URL segment? I would like to conditionally show code if the text "vascular" is in Segment 3.

If my URL is: `https://website.com/segment1/segment2/10009-vascular-access`

This is what I've tried so far...

```
{% if craft.request.getSegment(3) == 'vascular' %}

{% if craft.request.getSegment(3).contains("vascular") %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to utilize twig's built-in containment operator.

Your code would look like this:

```
{% if 'vascular' in craft.request.getSegment(3) %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Here is official documentation on the containment operator: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator.